# What are the meanings of `(uint256) (a)` and `(int256) (a)` in Solidity

Tags: solidity, ethereum-classic, overflow

I came across the following code
`payoutsTo_[_customerAddress] +=  (int256) (_dividends * magnitude);`

What is meaning of `(int256)` in this line, and is there any possibility of overflow here? Or here:
`magnitude = 2 ** 64`

Comment: What are the types of `_dividends` and `magnitude`?

Comment: both are uint256

Comment: And the type of `payoutsTo_`?

Comment: `mapping(address => int256) payoutsTo_`

Comment: Well then I've already answered your question several hours ago, based on that (as an assumption).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An educated guess:

Since you did not provide the type of variable `payoutsTo_`, I believe that it is:

```
mapping (address => int256) public payoutsTo_;
```

The following attempt of assigning a `uint256` value to an `int256` variable would not compile:

```
payoutsTo_[_customerAddress] += _dividends * magnitude;
```

Therefore, it is required to cast the value of `_dividends * magnitude` to `int256`.

---

> Is there any possibility of overflow here, with `magnitude == 2 ** 64`?

Yes, the value of `int256(_dividends * magnitude)` will:

- Turn negative when `2 ** (255 - 64) <= _dividends < 2 ** (256 - 64)`
- Wrap around when `2 ** (256 - 64) < _dividends`